# How to sync mysql and sqlite databases in Kotlin using volley

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to build an app(Kotlin) to store Bus ticket data which would work offline and online.
The flow :- 
a)Take the data entry -> Use volley to send it to remote MySQL db via JSON HTTP request
b)If mysql entry is succeeded, set the upload_status as 1(data is uploaded) -> store data to sqlite with status =1
c)If it doesn't sends to mysql (due to internet connection issue) set the upload_status as 0 (data is not uploaded to remote mysql) -> store data to sqlite with status = 0
Afterwards Im thinking to run a coroutine or some kinda jobscheduler to push the rows from sqlite with status 0 to mysql with a certain time frame.

Currently Im able to Send the data to mysql and sqlite if the network connection is working.
But if the connection is not working, then volley(Async task) starts trying for sending the data to mysql while the sqlite statements are executed before getting any response from volley. Due to late response from volley, cant set the status value with right value(i.e 0) and insert into sqlite

Below is my code from MainActivity.kt

```
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                try{

                    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+response+"]");
                    val obj = JSONObject(response)  
                    u_status = 1;
                    Log.i("Uploaded", "done1"+u_status.toString());

                  Toast.makeText(applicationContext,obj.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }catch (e: JSONException){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            object : Response.ErrorListener{
                override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError){
                    u_status = 0;
                    Log.i("ERROR TAG", "err1"+u_status.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }){

            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>{
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("origin", origin)
                params.put("destination", destination)
                params.put("AdultQt", AdultQt)
                params.put("ChildQt", ChildQt)
                return params
            }
        }

        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
        Log.i("TAG", "final1"+u_status.toString());

 val databaseHandler: DatabaseHandler= DatabaseHandler(this)

        if(origin.trim()!="" && destination.trim()!=""){
            val status = databaseHandler.addTicket(TicketModelClass(origin, destination, Integer.parseInt(AdultQt),Integer.parseInt(ChildQt),(u_status)))
            if(status > -1){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"record save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                editTextOrigin.text.clear()
                editTextDestination.text.clear()

            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"origin and destination cannot be blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

VolleySingleton.kt

```
import android.app.Application
import android.nfc.Tag
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class VolleySingleton : Application(){

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }


    val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
        get(){
            if(field == null){
                return Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            }
            return field
        }
    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(request: Request<T>){
        request.tag = TAG
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }

    companion object{
        private val TAG = VolleySingleton::class.java.simpleName
        @get:Synchronized var instance: VolleySingleton? = null
            private set
    }

}
```

Is there any possibility to make the main thread sleep till volley request gets executed so that I could get the status if its uploaded to Mysql or not. Or should I put both Mysql and sqlite insertion in volley(async tasks) so they could execute one after the other?. Is there any  better way to do the above mentioned? Since kotlin doesn't have much of examples, some examples would be great. Thanks!